# Make body scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I've created a table with javascript:

```
t=document.getElementById('tabby');

for(var k=1; k<=100; k++)
{
t.innerHTML+="<tr> <td> hello </td> </tr>";
}
```

Thing is, the page isn't scrollable. (which makes sense. The table isn't really there when the page is loaded.)

to solve this, I tried setting the body's overflow to scroll, after the table has formed:

```
document.getElementById('body').setAttribute('style', 'overflow:scroll;');
```

but it didn't help. (of course the id of the body is "body" and the table's is "tabby")

What should I do?

Thanks.

**edit:**

whoops.
seems like the position: absolute; i put in the table's style is casuing the trouble.

https://jsfiddle.net/t66dp7oc/

So what should i do if i need the position absolute and also the page scrollable?

Comment: side note: don't update innerhtml in a loop like that. it forces a redraw/rebuild of the dom tree very time. build your html as a simple string, then stick it into .innerhtml ONCE.

Comment: I think you might give this overflow to parent element of table, is it directly the body?

Comment: @MarcB excellent advice, thanks!

Comment: @divy3993 it's the body. iv'e tried to put the "overflow:scroll" in just about any element

Comment: @Yarin_007 The answer by taxicala is very true. If you are making this mistake, try it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've got it.

all i had to do is wrap the table with a div, and give the div the position absolute property. As for the table, i've given it the position: relative; property. works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I might not get the complete problem of your, but here is what you can try for the table. And this seems to be the best solution to me. Just try creating the variables outside the loop:

```
function tableCreate() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width = '100%';
    tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
    var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (i == 2 && j == 1) {
                break
            } else {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u0020'))
                i == 1 && j == 1 ? td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2') : null;
                tr.appendChild(td)
            }
        }
        tbdy.appendChild(tr);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
    body.appendChild(tbl)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `overflow` property does not apply to tables.

So you can change the `display` of the table to `block` or `inline-block`:

```css
table {
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Note this might break some tabular functionalities.

```js
var t = document.createElement('table'),
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.innerHTML = '<td>Hello</td>';
for(var i=0; i<100; ++i)
  t.appendChild(tr.cloneNode(true));
document.body.appendChild(t);
```

```css
table {
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should probably do:

```
document.body.setAttribute('style', 'overflow:scroll;');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var tableRows = '';
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  tableRows += "<tr> <td> hello </td> </tr>";
}
var tabby = document.getElementById('tabby');
tabby.innerHTML = tableRows;
```

Also, I would recommend using jQuery for stuff like this. It just makes it easier.